# nightwatch-cucumber ES6 --- nightwatch JS ES5

Tags: javascript, cucumber, nightwatch.js

I've read that nightwatch does not support ES6. Fair enough.

However, the documentation for [nightwatch-cucumber](http://mucsi96.github.io/nightwatch-cucumber/)

Looks like it uses ES6 (arrow functions) on the steps it defines as examples.

My question is: Is it possible to use ES6 on the cucumber steps and ES5 on the page objects for nightwatch? Or should I stick to ES5 for everything?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to write my cucumber steps in ES6  and my page objects in ES5. However it might be better to stick to ES5 to have consistency + I did notice I would get some strange failures (rarely) when using:

```
Given('Go to Site', () => client.url('https://google.com'));
```